# Random arrangement of English Alphabet; Finding probability that no two vowels are next to each other.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, permutations, combinations

So, in a random arrangement of the alphabet, the sample space will be $26^{26}$.
So, $P(\text{Sample Space}) = 26^{26}$
No two vowels next to each other might mean, consonants on 13 spaces and vowels on 13 slots.

Here's what I did:
Consider the event $A$.
$N(A) = 13^{21}$ ($13$ Slots for $21$ consonants, randomly). $13^5$ ($13$ slots for random $5$ vowels).

I am not getting the permutation part quite well
So, how do I proceed?

Comment: Arrangement = permutation, I suppose. So there will be exactly 5 (or 6?) positions with vowel letters. Once you have fixed these positions, we simply count arbitrary permutations of the vowel letters alone and the consonant letters alone. Main task: count the ways to pick the vowel letter positions. Use the so-called stars-and-bars technique!

Comment: One can consider as well that there are 6 vowels (most usually $Y$ is considered as a vowel).

Comment: I do not find your question clear.  Are you considering a permutation of the $26$ letters of the English alphabet (as your title implies) or a random string of letters of the English alphabet (in the body of your question, you seem to be considering strings with repetition)?  If it is a string, does it have $26$ letters?  Is the string required to have a certain number of vowels?  Please clarify.

Comment: @JeanMarie: No, in English the letter Y is usually _not_ considered a vowel (despite the fact that it does, in practice, often function as one). Whereas in French, teaching materials will talk about "les 6 voyelles", in English children are generally taught about "the 5 vowels".

Comment: @psmears Thank you very much for this precision. In a third language, german, "y" is considered as well as a vowel but the discrepancy with other languages is that it pronunced like a "ü" (with an "umlaut")

Answer (score 3):

Addendum added to respond to the comment of Jean Marie.

---

I am assuming that there are exactly $(5)$ vowels in the alphabet.  For $k \in \{0,1,2,3, \cdots, 13\}$, let $f(k)$ denote the number of ways that you can combine $(k)$ vowels and $26-k$ consonants into a $(26)$ character string where:

- Replacement is permitted  (i.e. you can re-use a letter).
- No two vowels can be together.

Then, the desired enumeration will be

$$\sum_{k=0}^{13} f(k), \tag1 $$

so, the problem has been reduced to providing a closed form expression for $f(k)$.

For a specific value of $(k)$, you will have $5$ choices for each of the $k$ vowel-positions and $21$ choices for each of the $(26-k)$ consonant positions.

Therefore, to enumerate $f(k)$, the first thing that is necessary is to create the factors

$$(21)^{(26 - k)} \times (5)^k. \tag2 $$

The factors in (2) above will be the first two factors used in the enumeration of $f(k)$.

For the sake of illustration, assume that $k = 10,$ and that you are (arbitrarily) going to form a 26 character word with $(16)$ Z's, and $(10)$ A's.  How many such 26 character words are possible, where none of the A's are next to each other.

To answer this question, you need a working knowledge of Stars and Bars Theory.
For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Consider the number of non-negative integer solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{11} = 16. \tag3 $$

This enumeration, which per Stars and Bars Theory is
$~\displaystyle \binom{16 + 10}{10}~$ is **close** but slightly different from the number of satisfying ways of combining the $10$ A's and $(16)$ Z's.

One good thing about the equation in (3) is that it **respects** the $(16)$ choices of consonants, which are to be placed around the $(10)$ vowels.  The other good thing is that with $(10)$ vowel positions to be used, the variables $x_1,\cdots,x_{11}$ nicely represent the **gaps** before the first vowel, after the last vowel, and between the vowels.

The only bad thing is that while it is okay for $x_1$ and $x_{11}$ to equal $(0)$, because these variables represent the gaps before the first vowel and after the last vowel, it is **not okay** for any of the other variables to equal $(0)$.

For example, if $x_2 = 0$, this analogizes to there being no gap between the first and second vowel.

The fix here is to change the variables:

For $k \in 2,3,\cdots,10$, let $y_k = x_k - 1.$

Then, you are interested in the number of non-negative integer solutions to

$x_1 + $ 
$y_2 + y_3 + \cdots + y_{10}$ 
$+ x_{11} = (16 - 9) = 7.$

So, for the specific use of $16$ Z's and $10$ A's, the enumeration is

$$\binom{7 + 10}{10}.$$

In general, for $k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,13\}$, you will want the number of non-negative integer solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{k+1} = (26 - k)$$

subject to the constraint that none of $x_2,x_3, \cdots, x_k$ are permitted to equal $(0)$.

The enumeration here is

$$\binom{[26 - k] + [k+1 - 1] - [k-1]}{k+1 - 1} = \binom{27-k}{k}. \tag4 $$

---

Putting it all together, the overall enumeration is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{13} ~\left[ ~(21)^{(26 - k)} \times (5)^k \times \binom{27-k}{k} ~\right]. \tag5 $$

So, the expression in (5) above represents the enumeration of the number of satisfying (**equally likely**) $(26)$ character strings.

To convert the enumeration into a Probability, simply multiply it by

$$\frac{1}{26^{(26)}}.$$

---

**Addendum** 
Responding to the comment of Jean Marie:

> As I remarked above, there are 6 vowels in the alphabet A,E,I,O,U and Y.

Except that $Y$ is sometimes uses as a consonant (e.g. the word "yardstick") and sometimes used as a vowel (e.g. the word "my").

To make sense out of the problem, a **decision** must be made, one way or another.  The OP (i.e. Original Poster) left a comment that he thought that there were $(5)$ or $(6)$ vowels.

That doesn't cut it.  You can't ask the responder to try and hit a **moving target**.  Normally, I try to anticipate the intent of the OP.

Here, there is certainly enough evidence in support of your viewpoint to justify including the **alternative** computation.

The only relevance to altering the number of vowels from $(5)$ to $(6)$ is that the factors of

$$(21)^{(26-k)} \times (5)^k$$

change to

$$(20)^{(26-k)} \times (6)^k.$$

Comment: As I remarked above, there are 6 vowels in the alphabet $A,E,I,O,U$ and $Y$. I know it is complex as one can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel).

Comment: @JeanMarie See the Addendum that I have just added to my answer.

Comment: Very well written addendum !

Answer (score 0):

(**Assuming repetition is allowed**)

Here's another way to count it. The number of allowed arrangements is given by sum of first row of

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
21 & 5 \\
21 & 0
\end{bmatrix} ^ {26}
$$
which is $2727004680535608837987658411692498651$. This follows when you consider it as a state machine, where states are $C = $ "previous was a consonant" and $V = $"previous was a vowel". Then the number of ways you can transition are indicated in the matrix, i.e you can append a consonant in $21$ ways and a vowel in $5$ ways. And if previous was a vowel, you can't append a vowel (hence the $0$ in the matrix). You start from the state $C$ because you can assume "previous" was a consonant when there's nothing (it makes no restrictions). Then take $26$ steps, i.e. append $26$ letters.